# How to convert the System Date into date format into Date Datatype

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I want to convert the current date with the help of the DateFormatter into Date datatype. I want the date to be in dd/mm/yyyy format and its datatype should be Date not string.
Here's the code I've tried and the output i am getting.

```
let date = Date()
print(date)//output - 2017-02-24 13:39:01 +0000
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let tempDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(tempDate)//output - 24/02/2017
let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: tempDate)
print(currentDate!)//output - 2017-02-23 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: You didn't specify hours/minutes/seconds, so it will be 0 (start of the day) once you convert it back from String to Date. But since I guess, you are in India with a +5:30 timezone from UTC, 18:30:00+0000 is your start of the day, it's equals to 00:00:00 +5:30. If you convert it back to String just after, you should have "24/02/2017"

Comment: i don't want hours/minutes/second thats why i have specified "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: change dateFormatter timezone
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:##)

Comment: still the same @MohamedMostafa

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Could you clarify what you want at the end?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You want to start with the current date from `Date()`. And you seem to want to end with a `Date` instance. What's all the needless stuff in between for? Just use `let date = Date()` and you are done.

Comment: @rmaddy i want the date in dd/mm/yyyy format and the instance should be Date only , whatever i have written in between is not useless . I am getting the output as i wanted but the instance is String i want it to be DATE

Comment: @Larme i have edited it please check it. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Ronit a date without a time doesn't exist. however you can display only the date part of a date using dateformatter

Comment: @Ronit You are still being very unclear. A `Date` instance is a snapshot in time. You can't have a `Date` with no time. It's only when you convert a `Date` to a `String` that you indicate what format you want. There is no need for you to go from `Date` to `String` and back to `Date`.

Comment: @rmaddy i have clearly mentioned it i want the date without time and the date should be date instance not string. i cannot send the date which is of String instance to the api as an parameter and it should be in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @Ronit Not possible. A `Date` is a point in time. Period. You can't do anything to change that. Why do you want a Date with no time? What is your actual goal here?

Comment: @rmaddy please check the above comment i have edited it.

Comment: The only way to have a `Date` in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` is to convert it to a `String`.

Comment: @rmaddy i have got the date but i cannot send the string to the api as parameter as it doesn't allow the parameter to be string , if i want data from the api then i need to send it in Date instance

Comment: @Ronit So send the `Date` instance. What's the issue?

Comment: @rmaddy i am not getting the date in dd/mm/yyyy format check the above code and it should be of date instance. the api need the date to be in dd/mm/yyyy format and i tried sending date of string instance it is giving error. thats why i have raised this question.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Update your question with details about your attempts to send a date to whatever API you are trying to use and clearly explain the error/issue you are having. You seem to have a complete misunderstanding of how `Dates` work here.

Comment: @rmaddy i m beginner , i might be doing something wrong , thanks for your help

Comment: Which is why I suggest you update your question with what you are actually trying to do so people can help you solve your issue. The question you posted here is not the right question.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that the output of `print(currentDate!)` equals `2017-02-24 00:00:00 +0000` set the `dateFormatter timeZone` to `GMT`

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0)
```

**Update**

I think that I understood your need. You want to truncate time from a `Date` object.

```
let date = Date()
print(date)
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
let currentdate = calendar.date(from: components)
print(currentdate!)
```

Comment: i don't want that output , i want the output to be in dd/mm/yyyy format and its datatype should be date not string. if i wanted the output as you mentioned i already had got it.

Comment: The update does not truncate time from a `Date`. That's not possible. What this updated code does is change the `Date` to be at midnight local time. That's very far from the "truncating time".